# Outgoing MSMQ timeout configuration

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

I have an application that uses NServiceBus to send and receive messages. When the application hasn't received a message in a certain time period the outgoing connection is lost which results in messages not being received on the application until it has been restarted or it initiates a message.

Is there a way to configure the MSMQ timeout?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "connection" to a queue, in the sense that it could be "lost". Neither is there an "MSMQ timeout". Can you re-word your question to explain what behaviour you are actually observing in more detail?

Comment: the connection state of the outgoing queue is becoming 'inactive' and consequently 'lost' -- [Screenshot](http://cl.ly/2Z1A0a241i3t2I2s0L0W)

Comment: An MSMQ outgoing queue will have different states depending on what it is asked to do. If it has nothing to deliver then it will be deleted after a few minutes of idle time. Outgoing queues are created on demand whenever a message is created and sent. You can change the idle time cleanup interval but you don't need to in your scenario. As Hugh mentioned, please explain what you are seeing in more detail as there is not enough information to advise on.

Comment: see this KB article: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8591350/264607

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments outgoing queues are temporary and will be removed if no messages are sent in a certain period of time. This can't cause message loss. Is this still a problem?