# Windows Message Queue, message does not arrive on server

Tags: c#, msmq

currently I am trying to write something in a transactual message queue on a remote machine:

```
string queueName = "FormatName:Direct=OS:servername\\private$\\testqueue";
var msgQueue = new MessageQueue(queueName);
var msg = new Message("Some body...");
msgQueue.Send(msg, MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
```

My local machine shows me a new message in the outgoing folder (if I pause it), it shows the correct IP and the numbers of messages change to 0, if I unpause it. So I guess the code part is correct.

But it never appears on the target message queue.

Security on the target queue is set to "allow everyone everything".

edit: 
End2End Tracing says:

On local machine:

1. Message with ID {...} queued in DIRECT=OS...
2. Message sent over network

On server:

1. Message came over network

But it's still not showing up the in message queue. Any ideas?

Comment: check if port is open `telnet server 1801`

Comment: Have you tried end to end tracing? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730882.aspx

Comment: Same problem and some troubleshooting you can find here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044365/msmq-messages-are-stuck-in-the-outgoing-queue

Comment: @marceln: I've added the result of the End2End tracing to my question.

Comment: If not solved yet, can you clarify if you have any clients on the other (receiving) end, that might pick up the message from the queue?

Comment: @marceln: I've created a fresh queue for my tests, so nothing could possibly pick it up.