# MSMQ - Insufficient resources to perform operation

Tags: localhost, windows-server-2008, msmq, c#-2.0

I've read https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732531/684646

I have the same issue...

And I've been striking possibilities taking into account that I know some facts:

- The queues are all empty
- There are some GBytes left of free space on the msmq server
- The messages have been working fine the past two years
- The messages are fixed in size, in less than 2Kb
- I've tried already restarting the service and changing the storage limits, with no changes.

So,

> From John Breakwell's Blog there are eleven possibilities:

**1. <s>The thread pool for the remote read is exhausted (MSMQ 2.0
    only).</s>**

There are no items in queue. *I'm not sure if that's enough info to strike this one.*

**2. The number of local callback threads is exceeded**

Didn't understand how to check this.

**3. <s>The volume of messages has exceeded what the system can handle (MSMQ 2.0
    only).</s>**

No way, it's empty. *Unless this is talking about an overflow of Ids*

**4. Paged-pool kernel memory is exhausted.**

Not sure how to check this. *[The document](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2006/09/18/761035.aspx) says something about using some command which I wasn't able to find.*

**5. <s>Mismatched binaries.</s>**

The product has been unchanged for years now. *(Unless microsoft sent an auto-update that screwed the binaries, which seems unlikely)*

**6. <s>The message size is too large.</s>**   Checked

**7. The machine quota has been exceeded.**

On [the document](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2006/09/18/761035.aspx) talks about *Machine quotas (a.k.a. storage limits)* If storage is this issue (too) it's checked, I'm a bit confused out here.

**8. Routing problems when opening a transactional foreign queue (MSMQ
        3.0 only)**

It's local the usage of the Queue. There's a local webservice called remotely, (impersonated locally) which inserts in the queue.

**9. <s>Lack of disk space.</s>**  Checked

**10. <s>Storage problems on mobile devices</s>**   Not mobile, Windows Server 2008

**11. Clustering too many MSMQ resources**

[The document](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2006/09/18/761035.aspx) says to check `SystemViewSize` on the registry. How do I check `SystemViewSize` on the registry?

Comment: @john-breakwell Could you give me a little help here? =)

Comment: How much space taken up by files in the windows\system32\msmq\storage folder?

Comment: some kbs, but I'll re-check. The problem was gone after rebooting.
Windows Server 2K8

Comment: Very likely that some other application used up all the kernel memory (item 4 in the list) so MSMQ couldn't allocate any to itself. You wrote that you couldn't check this step. What went wrong?

Comment: The document states to run "TMQ STATE" but I wasn't able to find the TMQ.

Comment: And today is at 10Mb of occupied space

Comment: if that's the case (point 4), how do I prevent that from happening? It's a productive server and I can't joyfully reboot it whenever this happens, I have to find a workaround. Any ideas?

Comment: My article says "TMQ is available from KnowledgeBase article 887220 "Description of TMQTools utilities for Microsoft Message Queuing"". The KB says "For additional information about how to download the TMQTools utilities, visit the following Microsoft Web site:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=5D1A9FA3-0964-4998-A306-D95280CEF8BB&displaylang=en"

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this problem by deleting all of the message files (.mq) found in the `C:\windows\system32\msmq\storage` directory.  I'm working in a development environment so I'm not worried about the loss of messages.  This might not be the best idea if you're in a production environment.

Hope this helps someone.